Characteristic method for first order PDEs and changing the initial condition.
I am trying to solve the following question:
Consider the initial-boundary value problem:
$u_t(x,t)+ u_x(x,t) = x, \quad  x > 0,\quad t > 0,$
$u(0,t) = t, \quad t > 0,$
$u(x, 0) = \sin(x), \quad x> 0.$
Solve this problem using the method of characteristics. Is the solution continuous along the line $x= t$? What happens instead if we choose as initial value $u(x,0) = \cos(x)$?
First I solve it using the method of characteristics. But, I got confused which initial condition to use.
I started with using the method of charactersitic using the first condition
$u(0,t)=t$,
I got  $t= $ $\tau$ $+s$ ; $x=$$\tau$ ; $z= $$\tau^2/2 +s$
So,  $z= x^2/2 +t-x$
If I chose the other condition $u(x,0)=sin(x)$
I got  $t= $ $\tau$ ; $x=$$\tau + s$  ; $z= $$\tau^2/2 +\tau s +sin(s)$
So,  $z= t^2/2 +(x-t)t + sin(x-t)$
I can see in both cases that for x=t, it will still be continuous for both cases and even for the new condition $u(x,0)=cos(x)$.
Any idea about what is intended in this questions.

Here is my solution. I am confused actually which initial condition I should use, and how to proceed.

I just edited it. Is there is anything I am missing?

Thank you for pointing that out, I just updated it. Any insights concerning my question?

Yes, but what will I benefit from them being equals after having $x=t$? You mean that this means I can choose any of the conditions? concerning $u(x,0)=cos(x)$, we will have the same as last expression but $cos(x-t)$ instead of $sin (x-t)$, which will gives us 1 after putting $x=t$. But, here I didn’t get what will this implies to answer the last part.

Using the Laplace transform, we get
$$
s\hat u(x,s) + \hat u_x(x,s) = \frac xs + u(x,0) = \frac xs + \sin x
$$
now solving this ode with initial conditions $\hat u(0,s) = \frac 1{s^2}$, we get
$$
\hat u(x,s) = \frac{e^{-s x} \left(2 s^3+s^2+e^{s x} \left(s^4 \sin (x)-s^3 \cos (x)+\left(s^2+1\right) (s x-1)\right)+s+1\right)}{s^3 \left(s^2+1\right)}
$$
with anti-transform
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} (\theta (t-x) ((t-x) (t-x+2)+2 \sin (t-x))-t (t-2 x)-2 \sin (t-x))
$$
where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside theta (unit step)  function.

$$u_t(x,t)+ u_x(x,t) = x$$
A first chararacteristic equation, is
$$t-x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation is
$$u-\frac{x^2}{2}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on explicit form is :
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=\frac{x^2}{2}+F(t-x)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (To be determined according to a boundary or initial condition).
Condition $u(0,t)=t$
$u(0,t)=F(t)=t$. The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $(t-x)$. The particular solution satisfying both the PDE and the condition is :
$$u(x,t)=\frac{x^2}{2}+(t-x)\tag 1$$
Condition $u(x,0)=\sin(x)$
$u(x,0)=\frac{x^2}{2}+F(-x)=\sin(x)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+-\sin(x)$. The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $(t-x)$. The particular solution satisfying both the PDE and the condition is :
$$u(x,t)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\left(-\frac{(t-x)^2}{2}-\sin(t-x)\right)$$
$$u(x,t)=x\,t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\sin(x-t)\tag 2$$
Condition $u(x,0)=\cos(x)$
$u(x,0)=\frac{x^2}{2}+F(-x)=\cos(x)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(x)$. The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $(t-x)$. The particular solution satisfying both the PDE and the condition is :
$$u(x,t)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\left(-\frac{(t-x)^2}{2}+\cos(t-x)\right)$$
$$u(x,t)=x\,t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\cos(x-t)\tag 3$$
IN ADDITION
Case of two conditions $u(0,t)=t$ and $u(x,0)=x$ applied together :
Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ are vadid each in a different domain.
On the frontier $x=t$ both functions give $u(x,t)=\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{t^2}{2}$. There is no discontinuity.
Case of two conditions $u(0,t)=t$ and $u(x,0)=\cos(x)$ applied together :
For $x=t$ Eq.$(1)$ gives $u=\frac{x^2}{2}$ while Eq.$(3)$ gives $u=\frac{x^2}{2}+1$. There is a discontinuity beteween the two domains. This discontinuity is the extension of the discontinuity at origin $u(0,0)=\sin(0)=0$ and $u(0,0)=\cos(0)=1$ even though the origin $(0,0)$ is outside the considered domain $x>0$ and $t>0$.

thank you for the clear explanation. So, for $x=t$, it is continuous in the 3 conditions, right?

I mean for the condition 2 with the $sin$  is continuous when substituting $x=t$. But with the $cos$ condition, it is not continuous.

See the addition at end of my answer.

Thank you for your insights. SO, with the condition $u(x,0)=\sin(x)$, it will be continuous. However, for the condition $u(x,0)=\cos(s)$ it is not.

Sorry I cannot understand what you mean.

I wanted to make sure that what you wrote means that the solution is continuous along the line $x=t$ with the condition $u(x,0)=\cos(x)$, but it is not continuous with the condition $u(x,0)=\sin(x)$

You did completely leave out the inequalities. The solution has obviously the positive quadrant as domain. $F(t)=t$ is only valid for $t>0$. For $x>0$ the second boundary condition gives $F(-x)=\frac{x^2}2-\sin x$ or $F(t)=\frac{t^2}2+\sin t$ for $t<0$. // In the second case $u(x,0)=\cos x$ one gets a shock wave/front starting from the origin (which might evolve into a dispersion front).
